# External Apple LED Cinema Display works intermittently with MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: display, displayport, cinema-display

I have a 15-inch mid-2014 MacBook Pro Retina. All the ports work perfectly (I've tested them individually with different peripherals). I recently purchased an Apple 24-inch LED Cinema Display from 2009 second-hand; the vendor is someone I trust, and the monitor and cables are all in working order.

[image]

The LED Cinema Display (LEDCD for short) has a power cable, which needs to be connected to a power outlet, and a second cable that splits into three cables: DisplayPort, USB 2 and one that goes into my laptop's charging port (it actually doesn't fit into my laptop's charging port, but I have an adapter). It needs to be connected to my laptop via either DisplayPort or USB. The cable that goes into the charging port is for using the LEDCD with my laptop closed (which I'm not interested in doing; I want two screens); I leave that one unplugged at all times.

I've connected the LEDCD to my laptop via DisplayPort (I tried via USB, didn't work). It works perfectly for a while (hours at a time): no flickers, blurry image or distortion of any kind. But then it stops working (the display goes completely dark, as if it were unplugged).

Unplugging it from my computer and replugging it doesn't work. Neither does unplugging it from the power outlet and replugging it. I've also tried putting my laptop to sleep and waking it up with the LEDCD connected, to no avail. If I leave it several hours and then plug it back into my laptop, it works again for a few hours before stopping once more. I tried restarting my laptop with the LEDCD connected. That made it last a little longer than usual, but then it stopped working, as before.

I've tried the relevant steps under "If the display image is blank or unusable" on [this site](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201177#1). I still have the problem. I haven't tried resetting my Mac's [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063) and [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295) because they don't seem to be related exactly to my problem (e.g. I'm not trying to use an iMac as an external display using Target Display Mode, I'm trying to use an external display as an external display).

Since the LEDCD is an Apple product, I didn't think I needed to download a driver to use it, but I might be wrong. It *is* five years older than my laptop, after all. However, there are no updates in the Apple Store (the site I linked to says to check for updates with the external display connected).

The LEDCD isn't Retina, of course. I doubt this is the problem, since it does work normally for a while, but I could be wrong.

The LEDCD doesn't get hot. I've checked a few times when it's stopped working, and it's always been at room temperature.

Please help.

Comment: At 10 years old, my first guess would be something in the display is getting 'tired', capacitors, power inverter etc. I'd give it straight back to the vendor, their problem.

Comment: What @Tetsujin said.  It sounds like if you allow it to cool, it starts to work again which points to a power supply issue. You could possibly find a replacement on the secondary market (eBay), but as stated, it’s 10+ years old.  You may get better value both in time and money getting a new display

Comment: But it *doesn’t* get hot. I get the bit about it being old, but I can’t afford a new one. I’ll go down to the Apple Store and see what they think.

Comment: tbh, these days you can buy a new monitor for the price of that one second hand. They were great at the time, but the technology is old now.

Comment: When the monitor goes off, is the white light in the bottom right corner blinking a code? There was a common problem with the Apple LED monitors that can be avoided by masking the center pin of the power cord where it plugs into the power brick.

Comment: @jalynn2 I don’t think we’re talking about the same monitor. Mine has no white light. I’ll edit the question with a photo.